# Multiple Views/Assets Folders in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So my question regards **Laravel 5.2** and is as follows.

I have a project where for the purposes of fast ***AB Testing*** i need to duplicate views **and any assets** that go along with those views.

Meaning that the goal is so that inside of my **resources** folder i have a structure like

- resources/
- a/
  views/
  resources/
- b/
  views/
  resources/

Is this something that's possible in **Laravel**? What implications would this have?

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at config/view.php:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/config/view.php

You can add in new paths for Laravel to load views from like so:

```
'paths' => [
    realpath(base_path('resources/views')), // default
    realpath(base_path('a/views')),
    realpath(base_path('b/views')), 
],
```

If you use the same structure/naming conventions you should be able to simply swap the paths in and out from a to b for quick testing.